# Should “to mean” take an infinitive or a gerund for its complement? Does it make any difference?

Tags: grammaticality, gerund-vs-infinitive

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct:

> 1. To be human means to have a choice.
>          *<sub><sup>**INFINITIVE CLAUSE**</sup></sub> means <sub><sup>**INFINITIVE CLAUSE**</sup></sub>*
> 2. To be human means having a choice. 
>          *<sub><sup>**INFINITIVE CLAUSE**</sup></sub> means <sub><sup>**GERUND CLAUSE**</sup></sub>*
> 3. Being human means to have a choice. 
>           *<sub><sup>**GERUND CLAUSE**</sup></sub> means <sub><sup>**INFINITIVE CLAUSE**</sup></sub>*
> 4. Being human means having a choice. 
>           *<sub><sup>**GERUND CLAUSE**</sup></sub> means <sub><sup>**GERUND CLAUSE**</sup></sub>*

Reading through each of them, I find all of them acceptable; but at the same time I get all the more confused.

I am aware of the rule that *to mean to do something* is an idiomatic expression expressing intent. But I think that this rule doesn’t apply in this context of giving a definition.

Do these mean the same thing, or is there some difference between them?

Comment: They're all "valid", but #2 & #3 might be criticised for the potentially clumsy juxtaposition of infinitive and continuous verb forms. So the question itself is either POB or proofreading.

Answer (score 1):

> a) *[The word or phrase] 'something' **means** [the same as the word or phrase] 'something'.*

- > = is a synonym for

> b) *Something **means** doing something.*

- > = involves

> c) *Someone **means** to do something.*

- > = intends

Your sentences, using pattern a)

> 'To be human' means 'to have a choice'. (two full infinitives)
>
> 'Being human' means 'having a choice'. (two gerunds)
>
> *'To be human' means 'having a choice'. &  * 'Being human' means 'to have a choice'. (why mix?)

Your sentences, using pattern b)

> Being human means having a choice. (subject verb phrase in the gerund, usually)
>
> To be human means having a choice. (subject verb phrase in the full infinitive, formal)

Your sentences, using pattern c), which is mistaken, since the subject is not a person…

> *To be human means to have a choice.
>
> *Being human means to have a choice.

You probably know the joke: Banana begins with b and finishes with f.

Making sense when correctly punctuated: 'Banana' begins with 'b', and 'finishes', with 'f'.

About the importance of punctuation… , [Lynne Truss's *Eats, Shoots & Leaves*](http://www.lynnetruss.com/pages/content/?PageID=8)

Comment: +1. Realistically, the OP must mean pattern b, which requires "... means having a choice"; she can hardly intend choice-having as a literal definition of humanity.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for breaking this down for me. Just a follow-up question to your comment: If I understand correctly, your rule suggests that pattern a always requires punctuation with single inverted commas. Or is punctuation only a way of making it more explicit. Because I'd argue that punctuation in the banana joke is more essential than in pattern a